# Rabbitmq Exchanges vs Queues

Tags: rabbitmq

Im trying to do some basic testing with amqp using rabbitmq.  I wrote a simple python script with pika to create an amqp client.  I first did it sending messages directly to a queue.  This worked well and was able to monitor performance with the web rabbitmq managment tool as well as "rabbitmqctl list_queues".  I next tried to send messages to an exchange using multiple queues with the receiver listen on all queues.  Im confused because when I use the exchange I can not longer see the queues in the management tool or rabbitmqctl.  How do i monitor queues when using exchanges?

```
###########################################
queue send code:
###########################################
channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')

msgCnt = 1

while True:
    msg = "'Hello World! Msg Count: "+str(msgCnt)+"'"
    channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                      routing_key='hello',
                      body=msg)
    print(" [x] Sent " + msg)
    msgCnt = msgCnt + 1
    time.sleep(1)

###########################################
exchange send code:
###########################################
queue = sys.argv[1]   #passing test.0001, test.0002 in diff clients.
channel.exchange_declare(exchange='test', type='topic')

msgCnt = 1

while True:
    msg = "'Hello World! Msg Count: "+str(msgCnt)+"'"
    channel.basic_publish(exchange='test',
                      routing_key=queue,
                      body=msg)
    print(" [x] Sent " + msg)
    msgCnt = msgCnt + 1
    time.sleep(1)

###########################################
consumer code:
###########################################
channel.exchange_declare(exchange='test',
                         type='topic')

result = channel.queue_declare(exclusive=True)
queue_name = result.method.queue

binding_keys = sys.argv[1:]

for binding_key in binding_keys:
    channel.queue_bind(exchange='test',
                       queue=queue_name,
                       routing_key=binding_key)

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print(" [x] Received %r" % body)

channel.basic_consume(callback,
                      queue=queue_name,
                      no_ack=True)

print(' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C')
channel.start_consuming()
```